# How to move fixed elements more smoothly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have some elements with `{position: absolute}`.
When I'm scrolling page I want to move this elements.

I set `window.addEventListener(scroll, this.handleScroll)`.

The simplified code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll {
  var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset;
  this.setState({scrollLeft: scrollLeft})
}
...
<div style={{position: "absolute", left: this.state.scrollLeft + "px" 
}}>
   content 
</div>
<div style={{position: "absolute", left: this.state.scrollLeft + "px" 
}}>
   content 
</div>
....
```

On my PC this works excellent, but on the phone I see some hangs when elements are moving. How can I move elements more smoothly?

Comment: It might be best to use the `fixed` position. Can you convert your element style to use `fixed` instead of `absolute` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @ArashMotamedi no, my elements are fixed only by x-asis

Comment: I see. I have a few thoughts to share, a couple ideas to try. Please see my answer below. Hope one of the suggestions proves helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the snippet of code you've provided, it seems that you're hooking the window scroll event to a handler that changes the `state` of your component, which in turn will update the position of your component. This arrangement will unfortunately be slow/jittery on not only phone browsers, but also on slightly older desktop browsers. React, while generally fast, has an internal timer which may occasionally dictate it to batch `state` updates (when too many state changes happen in a short period of time, which would be the case with window scroll events). So, currently you're in an uphill battle against:

- React's internal state transition engine (which times and batches updates), and
- The layout redrawing process which, due to use of `absolute` positioning choice, will have to do a lot of recalculation every time you request it to position your component in the right place.

You can improve the situation and get smoother results by:

- Using `fixed` position if at all possible. This will be natively handled by the browser, providing excellent refresh rate. If, as you've elaborated, you need the component fixed only in one axis, still see if you can start with the `fixed` position and adjust the floating axis using the window scroll callback.
- Handle the repositioning of the element outside of React's state transitioning flow. While creating your component, create `ref`s for them, and handle their positioning the plain-old Javascript way. Decoupling from the React state machine will likely improve things drastically. Here's how to get a reference to your DOM element: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html Once you have that ref, you can manipulate it directly on the window scroll callback and avoid waiting for React state updates.
- Use `translate-x` and `translate-y` instead of `left` and `top` to reposition your component. `translate` properties belong to the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) CSS directive group, and are fundamentally different from the `left` and `top` properties in that they don't require **layout re-render** which consume a lot of the browser's rendering time. You will likely gain a lot of performance improvement just by substituting your `left` and `top` properties with `translate-x` and `translate-y`. Additionally, if you couple this approach with the suggestion above (manipulating position outside of React state transition flow), you should see a greatly improved, much smoother, experience.

Comment: thanks a lot for this advices , I will try to follow your recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are trying to achieve here, which to my understanding is making the content have the same position as the current scrolling position, can be done by using `position: fixed` on certain elements.

From MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

This will make the content stick on the screen regardless of your scrolling position, so it kind of "follows" you as you scroll.

Comment: No, my elements are fixed only by x-asis